# Async not working and printing infinite loop with other functions

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to figure out why my async function results in console.log(currentprice) results in an infinite loop. Should I not use async? I am trying to get the getCurrent() returned variable in the findMatch() function. Thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Your stock portfolio went from <?php echo $oldstock ?> to <?php echo $currentstock?>. That is a <?php echo $cleanpercent?>% change.</h1>
<p>Current Bitcoin price: <span id = "currentprice"></span></p>
<script>

const current_url = 'https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json';
async function getCurrent(curr){
        const response = await fetch(current_url);
        const data = await response.json();
        const currprice = data.bpi.USD.rate

        document.getElementById('currentprice').textContent = currprice;
        findMatch(currprice);
        return currprice;
}

getCurrent();



async function findMatch(){
    var currentPrice = 0;
    getCurrent.resolve(currentPrice);
    console.log(currentPrice);
    var percentChange = "<?php echo $cleanpercent ?>";
    console.log(percentChange);
    //todo percent change is a string
    var targetPrice = currentPrice * ((100+percentChange)/100);
    console.log(targetPrice);
}

findMatch();


</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the `curr` parameter to `getCurrent()` for? You never use it, and you don't pass an argument when you call the function.

Comment: Then you call `findMatch()` with an argument, but it doesn't take a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

`findMatch()` doesn't need to be async. It should just use its argument.

```
function findMatch(currentPrice){
    console.log(currentPrice);
    var percentChange = "<?php echo $cleanpercent ?>";
    console.log(percentChange);
    //todo percent change is a string
    var targetPrice = currentPrice * ((100+percentChange)/100);
    console.log(targetPrice);
}
```

I don't see the point of calling it from the top-level after the definition, it will be called from `getCurrent()`.